# Solution for mobile browser does not automatically delete empty table column

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table for game ranking display purpose.

Every game round the server will send all player's information to the client and the client will update these information to the table.

The numbers of players is from 1 to 4 thus the table is set to have 4 columns to accommodate the maximum needs.

The table need to display columns according to the player number (etc, 1 column if 1 player playing and 2 columns if 2 players playing)

So my solution is first to check if a player's information exist, if yes then write information to the table otherwise do nothing.

This solution works fine with most browsers as many browsers will automatically "delete" extra columns if no information to this column.

But some mobile browser will still display these "empty" column and cause aesthetic issue:

[image: screenshot from my mobile]

Is there a way to fix this problem (etc, delete the extra `td` tag in table?)

Here is the fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/h6tkgbb8/1/

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please provide us more details.

Comment: "Empty" columns will still be there, but might be collapsed to zero (or nearly zero) width if there's no content. Why are you adding empty columns?

Comment: Browsers doesn't "automatically delete" empty `td` columns. It doesn't happen ever. However you can write a JS script to check and delete those unnecessary columns as you wish.

Comment: Because there will be 1-4 players So I just have the table's columns number pre-set to 4, and then delete the unnecessary ones depending on the player number. Maybe I could do the other way around: pre-set the columns number to 0 and add necessary columns depending on the player number.@ RobG

Comment: Should I use the deleteCell() method? The problem is I only need to delete the columns once. Because the game will go on, from round 2 onwards I wont need to delete anything as all the unnecessary columns should be deleted after round 1 already. @Inuka

Comment: Will try to give you a dynamic table layout solution via JS. As your players grows then the table will update too.

Comment: I'm sorry it took some time to give you an answer. I was out of the office. Check out my answer. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to dynamically create table structure to your need.

```js
var information = [{
  name: "player1",
  rounds: "r1",
  penalized: "p1",
  wins: "1",
  loss: "1"
}, {
  name: "player2",
  rounds: "r2",
  penalized: "p2",
  wins: "1",
  loss: "1"
}, {
  name: "player3",
  rounds: "r3",
  penalized: "p3",
  wins: "1",
  loss: "1"
}]

var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id", "table");

var row, theader, tcell, keys = null;

//create first row of the table (table header) 
row = table.insertRow();
theader = document.createElement('th');
theader.innerHTML = "ranking";
row.append(theader);

//create table header data
for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
  theader = document.createElement('th');
  theader.innerHTML = "player " + eval(i + 1);
  row.append(theader);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    //create second row of the table
    row = table.insertRow();
    tcell = document.createElement('td');
    keys = Object.keys(information[0]);
    tcell.innerHTML = keys[1];
    row.append(tcell);
    //generate player rounds data
    for (var j = 0; j < information.length; j++) {
      tcell = document.createElement('td');
      tcell.innerHTML = information[j].rounds;
      row.append(tcell);
    }
  } else {
    //create third row of the table
    row = table.insertRow();
    tcell = document.createElement('td');
    keys = Object.keys(information[0]);
    tcell.innerHTML = keys[2];
    row.append(tcell);
    //generate player penalized data
    for (var j = 0; j < information.length; j++) {
      tcell = document.createElement('td');
      tcell.innerHTML = information[j].penalized;
      row.append(tcell);
    }
  }
}

//add whole table to the div
document.getElementById("table-wrapper").append(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 350px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

td {
  height: 25px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

th {
  background-color: #0A7E8C;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-wrapper"></div>
```

As you can see if you need to add more player details the table will automatically adjust your `HTML table` view.

If you want to add wins and loss to the table, do the following.

```js
var information = [{
  name: "player1",
  rounds: "r1",
  penalized: "p1",
  wins: "1",
  loss: "1"
}, {
  name: "player2",
  rounds: "r2",
  penalized: "p2",
  wins: "1",
  loss: "1"
}, {
  name: "player3",
  rounds: "r3",
  penalized: "p3",
  wins: "1",
  loss: "1"
}]

var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id", "table");

var row1, theader, tcell, keys = null;

//create first row of the table (table header) 
row = table.insertRow();
theader = document.createElement('th');
theader.innerHTML = "ranking";
row.append(theader);

//create table header data
for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
  theader = document.createElement('th');
  theader.innerHTML = "player " + eval(i + 1);
  row.append(theader);
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  switch (i) {
    case (1 && 2):
      row = table.insertRow();
      tcell = document.createElement('td');
      keys = Object.keys(information[0]);
      tcell.innerHTML = keys[1];
      row.append(tcell);
      //generate player rounds data
      for (var j = 0; j < information.length; j++) {
        tcell = document.createElement('td');
        tcell.innerHTML = information[j].rounds;
        row.append(tcell);
      }

      row = table.insertRow();
      tcell = document.createElement('td');
      keys = Object.keys(information[0]);
      tcell.innerHTML = keys[2];
      row.append(tcell);
      //generate player penalized data
      for (var j = 0; j < information.length; j++) {
        tcell = document.createElement('td');
        tcell.innerHTML = information[j].penalized;
        row.append(tcell);
      }

      break;
    case (3 && 4):
      row = table.insertRow();
      tcell = document.createElement('td');
      keys = Object.keys(information[0]);
      tcell.innerHTML = keys[3];
      row.append(tcell);
      //generate player wins data
      for (var j = 0; j < information.length; j++) {
        tcell = document.createElement('td');
        tcell.innerHTML = information[j].wins;
        row.append(tcell);
      }

      row = table.insertRow();
      tcell = document.createElement('td');
      keys = Object.keys(information[0]);
      tcell.innerHTML = keys[4];
      row.append(tcell);
      //generate player loss data
      for (var j = 0; j < information.length; j++) {
        tcell = document.createElement('td');
        tcell.innerHTML = information[j].loss;
        row.append(tcell);
      }
      break;
  }
}

//add whole table to the div
document.getElementById("table-wrapper").append(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 350px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

td {
  height: 25px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

th {
  background-color: #0A7E8C;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: This code did work perfect mate. And it is quite dynamic and meets my specific needs.Thank you so much! I just however discover a issue that this code has some problem with the IE browser. If I run this code with IE the table element wont rendered and I'd get the error "message" : "Object doesn't support property or method 'append'", "lineno": 70. Is the "append" method the culprit? I tried Jquery html() too but did not work either.

Comment: Will try to accommodate to cross browser compatibility. Thank you very much for your compliments sir. :) again I'm out of the office atm. Will do an update right after i go back.

Comment: Just for the moment, try including jQuery for your project please.

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing foo.append() to $("#foo1").append(). seems like IE is more strict on the syntax..

Comment: @jindsay yes I happened to read that on another SO answer as well. Anyways I'm hoping to improve my answer in future by replacing 'information[j].loss' that loss key to get from the array. So atm you have to replace that key to match with the json array. This will be automated in future.